# pass value from one form to another if bootstrap value is yes asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with a text field to allow the user to search for an MRN. If the MRN exists, they can add a new encounter. If the MRN doesn't exist, they can add a new patient. When they click on the search button, it pops up this modal:

```
if (searchresult != null)
        {
            lblModalTitle.Text = "This MRN exists!";
            lblModalBody.Text = "Would you like to add a new encounter for this patient?";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "EncounterModal", "$('#EncounterModal').modal();", true);
            upEncModal.Update();
        return;
        }
        else
        {
            PatModalTitle.Text = "This MRN does not exist!";
            PatModalBody.Text = "Would you like to add a new patient to the database?";
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "PatientModal", "$('#PatientModal').modal();", true);
            upPatModal.Update();

        }
```

If they select 'Yes' in the modal, I want to populate the MRN textbox in the NewPatient or NewEncounters page with the MRN from the Search page. This is what the code for my modal looks like:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="PatientModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="PatientModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPatModal" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><asp:Label ID="PatModalTitle" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <asp:Label ID="PatModalBody" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="NewPatientBtn" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" value="send" OnClientClick="window.location.href='NewPatient.aspx;">Yes</asp:LinkButton>

                    <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">No</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </div>
```

All the methods I've tried bypass the modal and load the next page, or they simply don't work. I just need a basic fix as it's for an internal web form app. Right now I'm using this in the source page:

```
 protected void SearchMRN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Session["mrn"] = SearchMRN.Text;
Server.Transfer("NewPatients.aspx");
}
```

And this in the target page:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
PAT_MRN.Text = Session["mrn"].ToString();
Session.Remove("mrn");
}
```

The modal pops up, but I keep getting a 'JS1015: Unterminated string constant' error, and it does not load the next page. Please help! I'd appreciate it very much. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. This is what works for me.

In my SearchMRN_Click class after executing the search, I do:

```
    HttpCookie C = new HttpCookie("MRN");
    C.Value = SEARCH_MRN.Text;
    Response.Cookies.Add(C);
```

And in NewPatients.aspx (target page)

```
        if(Request.Cookies["MRN"] != null)
    { PAT_MRN.Text = Request.Cookies["MRN"].Value; }
```

No need for a `Response.Redirect` because the modal will pop up and do the redirecting after prompting the user with the choice.